# Повторный запрос prompt, при введении неподходящего значения

Tags: javascript, циклы, while

Предположим задана переменная:

```
var variable1 = prompt ('Write "2", please');
```

Нужно чтобы, если пользователь вводит другое значение, нежели "2", появлялось сообщение об ошибке. Сделать это можно при помощи `if`.

**Вопрос** - как сделать так, чтобы после сообщения об ошибке, каждый раз (циклично) снова появлялся `prompt` с тем же вопросом, и чтобы чтобы введенное в него значение отдавалось переменной `variable1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заключите `prompt`, например, в цикл `while`

```
while ( true )
{  
    var variable1 = prompt ('Write "2", please');

    if ( variable1 == 2 ) break;

    alert( "Error. Invalid value" ); 
}
```

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Да не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Comment: Это точно, спасибо)! 
Единственное что - после выполнения цикла у меня почему-то виснет редактор кода, проверял дважды, странно, вроде бы никаких бесконечных циклов не создается... В браузере все работает без помех, видимо проблема в редакторе.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin По этому поводу я ничего сказать не могу. Но имейте в виду, что переменная будет содержать строку "2", а не число.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!